# Amazing android runtime issue with multidex?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-multidex

[image]

Look at the above picture, In my class, the return type of `getADPlayerPresenter()` is `com.miguplayer.player.f.a` but In runtime, the return type of `getADPlayerPresenter()` is  `com.miguplayer.player.e.a`, So the program is crash with exception `"No virtual method getADPlayerPresenter()Lcom/miguplayer/player/e/a;"`

Has anyone had a similar problem and fix it?

Comment: classes that you have highlighted are different. One is f.a. while the one in error log is /e/a

Comment: maybe you messed up with proguard